# "Review," "preview," "ask," or "request"?

Tags: word-choice, difference

> if the worker asks to review

> if the worker asks to preview

> if the worker requests to review

> if the worker requests to preview

Which sentence is better? Is there any better way to say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Review* - Assess, examine, add notes and corrections, give opinion or summary. You usually review someone else's work, possibly after it's been released (review a movie for a newspaper)

*Preview* - see before it is released as final version, possibly to satisfy curiosity. (preview a post before posting it on a forum)

*Ask* is more polite than *Request*. *Request* can be synonymous with *Demand* or *Order*, while *Ask* will be almost always polite and expecting refusal as an acceptable option.

Comment: Request is definitely very polite. A request is the opposite of an order; request means you're asking to be allowed something. `request: the act or an instance of asking for something` from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/request)

Comment: @WendiKidd: I'd disagree. While it's not rude, it's much more definite than just asking. *I request he stops immediately!* *I request to talk to the manager* *The list of the union requests that need to be satisfied in order to end the strike..." - that is not polite asking.

Comment: Definition #6 at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/request?s=t): `verb (used with object) 6.
to ask for, especially politely or formally: *He requested permission to speak.*` A *request* is a polite way to ask for something. A demand or an order is indeed impolite, but these are not synonymous with `request`.

Comment: @SF. The reason your examples are not polite is because of the context. *I ask that he stop immediately!* and *I'm asking to talk to the manager* are just as rude as your examples.

Comment: Usages overlap, but *on average* ***request*** is more likely to occur in polite/formal contexts. In evidence, note that ***requested him*** is almost 20 times less common than ***asked him*** in Google Books. But ***humbly requested him***, which I think is a strong indicator of polite/formal contexts, occurs almost as often as ***humbly asked him***. Obviously the verb *to ask* is itself far more common than *to request*, but that says nothing about the connotations of either word.